# Make it easier to see the 15 character minimum warning for the title when asking a new question

Tags: feature-request, title, asking-questions

I'm unable to create a new topic/question on SO.

When I click "Post Your Question", it turns grey and just hangs.

I've tried using both Firefox and Chrome and I'm not able to post a new question to SO.

Help please.

**Edit**

The issue was resolved, but could we make the title minimum character requirement more obvious when posting new questions?

Comment: Looks like I can post to Meta but just not SO. Hmm

Comment: @Coehoorn: Now it is a dupe.

Comment: I'm deleting my answer since it's completely off-topic now that the question has been edited to reflect the real problem. :)

Comment: Jeff already set it to `status-completed`: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25215/title-required-at-least-15-characters-error-hard-to-see

Comment: How about getting rid off this completely arbitrary minimum? While we're at it, we might as well throw away the minimum for comments.

Comment: @Manni: Join my club ;) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/700/can-we-get-rid-of-the-threshold-of-15-chars-for-comments

Comment: Done. lalalalala lala.

Answer (score 3):

I found the issue, my Title only had 14 characters and not the required 15 character.

You guys might want to make this MUCH more obvious if that's the problem from allowing someone make a post